# Conditional statements with more than 1 word in the same variable

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a variable based in various business rules from another variable. Please see example below. When I am dealing with only one word I need to use as a condition I use the following code:

```
  physical = ['light', 'sedentary', 'medium', 'heavy']

  def matcher(x):
      for i in physical:
          if i.lower() in x.lower():
             return i
          else:
             return 'other'
```

My issue is when that are multiple words that match in a sentence, in this specific cases I want to call `mix`. For example if more than one of the words appear in a sentence as on the first sentence then 'mix'

```
  Physical Demand                                          Result
    Light to medium with occasional heavy  levels           mix                        
    Light lifting                                           light
    Medium effort required when lifting                     medium
```

tks.

Comment: You're never returning `mix` here

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question. Your list doesn't contain mix as a string! How could you return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all item to return `mix` instead of directly return after just check one item. Next is a workable code, FYI.

```
physical = ['light', 'sedentary', 'medium', 'heavy']

def matcher(x):
    l = [item for item in physical if item.lower() in x.lower()]
    length = len(l)

    if length == 0:
        return 'other'
    elif length == 1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        return 'mix'

print(matcher('Light to medium with occasional heavy  levels'))
print(matcher('Light'))
print(matcher('Medium'))
print(matcher('abcde'))
```

Output:

```
mix
light
medium
other
```

Comment: tks for your solution worked perfectly. If I want to name the result based on what it found, for example if find light then 'the work is light' , if find medium then ' this is a medium type of work' . Where do I add on the function?

Comment: `if 'light' == l[0]: then return 'work work is light' elif 'medium' == l[0] return 'this is a medium type of work'`

Comment: tks a lot, im moving from R to python and still struggling a little bit. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to track if you have previously seen another value rather than returning the first value seen

For example

```
 def matcher(x):
    val = None
    for p in physical:
        for y in x.split():  # assuming x is a string 
            if p == y.lower():  # physical elements are already lowercase 
                if val is not None: 
                    # val already has a value, so you have more than one physical element in x 
                    return 'mix' 
                val = p
        return val if val else 'other'
```